# Passing variables to command line script

Tags: mysql, command-line, coldfusion

I have the following script that is meant to create a mysql database on a remote server using values passed into it:

```
set arg1=\\192.168.0.254\e$\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin
set arg2=192.168.0.254
set arg3=%1

echo %arg1%
echo %arg2%
echo %arg3%

pushd %arg1%
mysql -uignite -h %arg2% -p***** -e "CREATE DATABASE %arg3%"

pause
```

If I place a value in arg3, i.e. MYDatabaseName, then the script runs and fine from a web page that use the following coldfusion code to call the script:

```
<cfexecute name="E:\Domains\ignite.flinthosts.co.uk\wwwroot\domains\processes\database\MySQL\AddDatabase.cmd"
arguments="'MyDatabaseName'">
</cfexecute>
```

But if I keep the %1 in there - ie the holder for the variable - then it doesn't seem to pick it up and create the database.

Am I using the correct syntax to pass the variable into the file?

Comment: You could try passing arguments as an array - i.e. `arguments=#['MyDatabaseName']#` ?

Comment: Does the script work with the `%1` argument if you call it from the command line (not from ColdFusion)?  If so, what is the command line that you used?  If not, then you need to get it working this way first and then try to make the call from ColdFusion.

Comment: hi, yes we have called it from the command prompt and it works correctly passing through the variable value

Comment: Okay, so what does your command line look like when you call it from the command prompt?

Comment: You should capture and dump the output of command. See if it yields any clues. ie See attributes: `variable/outputFile` and `errorVariable/errorFile`.

Comment: you should use a more specific tag for the shell software you're using. Is this a .bat file or Powershell script? (It's not linux/unix shell syntax! ;-) ). Good luck!

Comment: Hi All - it's just windows command line.

I've put outputfile file in the cfexecute and there is nothing that gets written to the file.

The commandline is:- pathtofile.cmd DatabaseName - ie: cd     c:\dir\adddatabase.cmd mydatabase

Comment: That example does not have single-quotes around the database name. Why are you including singe-quotes in the ColdFusion call?  They should not be necessary and might be the problem.